# a quotient of prime ideal $$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just happened to be reading this [PDF](https://www.cimat.mx/~luis/seminarios/Teoria-de-Numeros/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf).
35-page says "quotient $^n / ^{n+1}$".
However I don't understand this.
$$ is a prime ideal, so it's not necessarily a ring.
Therefore it won't be a quotient ring.

What is "quotient $^n / ^{n+1}$"?

Comment: It is viewed as an $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$-vector space, as Neukirch writes, if you  prefer this. Here $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}\cong \Bbb F$ is a field.

Comment: The notation (in this context) actually only needs abelian groups.  It doesn't have to be a ring to use the quotient notation.  And when it is a ring it is still the same set as the quotient group (just with added structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$^i / ^{i+1}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_K$-module.

In fact, the text says:

> $^i / ^{i+1}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_K/$-vector space

Note that $\mathcal{O}_K/$ is a field because $$ is maximal, since  $\mathcal{O}_K$ is Dedekind.

Comment: ok, I understand. ^n / ^{n+1} is a quotient group, whence it is a module.